# Using str_replace on a string returned from a method call

Tags: php, string

This is the client code; I want to surround the the myReplaceRR inside the Magento string:

**BEFORE**

```
$myReplaceRRR=stripslashes($product_description);
$myReplaceRRR=str_replace("bespoke.php", "made-to-measure.php", $myReplaceRRR);
$myReplaceRRR=str_replace("***OFFER PRICE FOR A LIMITED PERIOD ONLY***", "<span style=\"color:#ed2929\">***OFFER PRICE FOR A LIMITED PERIOD ONLY***</span>", $myReplaceRRR);
echo $myReplaceRRR;
```

**AFTER**

```
$myReplaceRRR= $this->getChildHtml('description');
$myReplaceRRR=stripslashes($product_description);
$myReplaceRRR=str_replace("bespoke.php", "made-to-measure.php", $myReplaceRRR);
$myReplaceRRR=str_replace("***OFFER PRICE FOR A LIMITED PERIOD ONLY***", "<span style=\"color:#ed2929\">***OFFER PRICE FOR A LIMITED PERIOD ONLY***</span>", $myReplaceRRR);
echo $myReplaceRRR;
```

Note, I want this as a string `$this->getChildHtml('description');`

Comment: what is your actual question? Not demand...

Comment: Your `after` version is working with an undefined `$product_description`, and you'll just end up with an empty $myReplaceRRR at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really try to be more descriptive in your question.

Remove the second line?

```
$myReplaceRRR= $this->getChildHtml('description');
$myReplaceRRR=str_replace("bespoke.php", "made-to-measure.php", $myReplaceRRR);
$myReplaceRRR=str_replace("***OFFER PRICE FOR A LIMITED PERIOD ONLY***", "<span style=\"color:#ed2929\">***OFFER PRICE FOR A LIMITED PERIOD ONLY***</span>", $myReplaceRRR);
echo $myReplaceRRR;
```